# Leer archivo XML de Factura

Tags: php, xml

Estoy haciendo un código para leer las facturas de MX, mando guardar el archivo en una carpeta en el servidor y una vez guardaddo, llamo la siguiente función a la que le mando el nombre del archivo. Alguna mejor propuesta que vean en el código?

> public function LeerFactura($Folio){
>       error_reporting(0); 
>       $this->load->model("m_ingresos", "datos");
>       $ruta='http://www.dominio.com/uploads/FacturasEmitidas/'.$Folio.'.xml';
>       $xml = simplexml_load_file($ruta, null, true)
>       or die('Error al cargar XML');

```
$ns = $xml->getNamespaces(true);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('c', $ns['cfdi']);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('t', $ns['tfd']);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('r', $ns['registrofiscal']);

$Cantidad=0;
$Importe= 0; 
$Precio=  0;       
$ClaveProdServ = '-';
$Concepto= '';

foreach ($xml->xpath('//cfdi:Comprobante') as $cfdiComprobante){       
$version=$cfdiComprobante['Version']; }  

$unico=0;//************Se inicializa el número de conceptos en cero 
  if($version=="3.3"){
    foreach ($xml->xpath('//cfdi:Comprobante') as $cfdiComprobante){ 
          echo "Factura versión: ".$cfdiComprobante['Version']; 
          echo " "; 
         $NoFactura=$cfdiComprobante['Folio']; 
         $Fecha=$cfdiComprobante['Fecha']; 
         $Metodo=$cfdiComprobante['FormaPago']; 
         $Subtotal=$cfdiComprobante['SubTotal']; 
         $Total=$cfdiComprobante['Total']; 
    }    
    if(!$NoFactura){
        foreach ($xml->xpath('//r:CFDIRegistroFiscal') as $Complementos) {
            $NoFactura=$Complementos['folio']; 
        }
    }
    //******************************************
    foreach ($xml->xpath('//cfdi:Comprobante//cfdi:Emisor') as $DomicilioFiscal){ 
       $ProveedorRFC=$DomicilioFiscal['Rfc']; 
       $nombre=$DomicilioFiscal['Nombre'];
    }   
    foreach ($xml->xpath('//cfdi:Comprobante//cfdi:Receptor') as $Receptor){ 
       $ReceptorRFC=$Receptor['Rfc']; 
    }   
    foreach ($xml->xpath('//cfdi:Comprobante//cfdi:Impuestos//cfdi:Traslados//cfdi:Traslado') as $Traslado){ 
       $IVA= $Traslado['TasaOCuota']; 
    } 
    foreach ($xml->xpath('//cfdi:Comprobante//cfdi:Conceptos//cfdi:Concepto') as $Concepto){ 
       $Concepto= $Concepto['Descripcion']; 
        $unico++;
    }
}   
    echo $ProveedorRFC;
    echo " - "; 
    echo $nombre; 
    echo " ";       
if($unico>1){$Concepto="Varios";} 
$data = $this->datos->getRegMovimientosPorXML(
    $ProveedorRFC,
    $ReceptorRFC,
    $Fecha,
    $NoFactura,
    $Subtotal,
    $Total,
    $Concepto,
    $Metodo,
    $Indice
);
if($version=="3.3"&&$data){ 
    foreach ($xml->xpath('//cfdi:Comprobante//cfdi:Conceptos//cfdi:Concepto') as $Concepto){ 
    $Importe= $Concepto['Importe']; 
    $Precio=  $Concepto['ValorUnitario'];      
    $ClaveProdServ = $Concepto['ClaveProdServ'];
    $Cantidad= $Concepto['Cantidad'];  
    $Concepto= $Concepto['Descripcion'];            
    }
}   
}

}
```

Comment: No me dejaba poner el código completo así que recurrí a poner la primer parte en una cita y mutilar las demás partes como comentarios etc, si alguien tiene un consejo de como subir el código completo se lo agradeceré. O si alguien lo requiere solo escriba.

Comment: disculpa mi ignorancia dices xml pero que otro lenguaje estas usando

Comment: La lectura del xml, la hago en código de php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con la clase `SimpleXMLElement` no necesitas registrar namespace:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$xml="";
try{
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($strContenido);
}catch(Exception $e){
    $arrResp = array(false,array("descripcionError"=>"Problema al leer el archivo. El archivo XML es inválido.","errorPAC"=>false));
    return $arrResp;
}

$regimen=$xml->xpath("/cfdi:Comprobante/cfdi:Emisor/@RegimenFiscal");
$regimenFiscal=intval(trim($regimen[0]->RegimenFiscal));

$versionXmlXpath = $this->xml->xpath("/cfdi:Comprobante/@Version");
$versionCFDI =  "".trim($versionXmlXpath[0]->Version);
```

Tampoco necesitas hacer ciclos para obtener los valores de los nodos. Existen tres tipos de nodos XML: Los que son `datos primitivos`, los que son `datos complejos`, estos al final no importa como los leas porque son una agrupación de datos primitivos. Por ultimo están los nodos que son `listas` es decir donde el nodo hijo se puede repetir varias veces. Para los nodos que son `listas` es el único caso donde si tienes que hacer ciclos, por ejemplo el nodo `Conceptos` tiene `Concepto` y este se puede repetir varias veces. Ejemplo:

```
$noNodosConcepto=count($xml->xpath("/cfdi:Comprobante/cfdi:Conceptos/cfdi:Concepto"));
    for($cc=1;$cc<=$noNodosConcepto;$cc++){
        $noNodosTraslado=count($xml->xpath("/cfdi:Comprobante/cfdi:Conceptos/cfdi:Concepto[".$cc."]/cfdi:Impuestos/cfdi:Traslados/cfdi:Traslado"));
        $noImpuestosTrasIVA=0;
        for($tt=0;$tt<$noNodosTraslado;$tt++){
            $impuestoTrasladoIVA=$xml->xpath("/cfdi:Comprobante/cfdi:Conceptos/cfdi:Concepto[".$cc."]/cfdi:Impuestos/cfdi:Traslados/cfdi:Traslado/@Impuesto");
            if($impuestoTrasladoIVA[$tt]->Impuesto=="002" ){
                $noImpuestosTrasIVA++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Yo trato de usar en la medida de los posible mas `xpath` y menos `arreglos` porque siento que hay mas control de lo que estoy accediendo. Para mi la forma en que lo tienes suele ser confusa porque a veces no sabes que regresa `php`: un `objeto` o un `arreglo`.